# Get Text information sort and number them an put ";" after number and after each block

Tags: javascript, regex

Again some Problems.

I' get some values of a Textfield ,shown like them:

134.45   987.46   -89.10
 
   224.67   127.26   -19.12
   764.32   187.96   -78.25
...and so on...

I'm get them with

```
function LineWriteToNp01() { 
var getNP01TableData = $('#null_tabelle_dues1_text').text();
}
```

i need them in 
1;134.45;987.46;-89.10< br /><<< yes also the break - it will written in a .TXT file >>>
 
2;224.67;127.26;-19.12< br />
3;764.32;187.96;-78.25< br />
...and so on...

I couldn't figure it out how to. seems insoluble :(

Comment: What do you sort? Everything appears to be in the same order as before you start.

Comment: You don't use <br> in plain text: try `\n`.

Comment: the sps-modules in the machine, which will read later this txt file Need it like that what i've described......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hekp from "guest271314" was perfekt. i've built it a Little more dynamic.

```
 function LineWriteToNp01() {
var getNP01TableData = $('#null_tabelle_dues1_text').text().replace(/\s+X/, "");
var arr = getNP01TableData.split(/\s+/);
var _arr = [];
var index = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= (arr.length-1)/3; i++) {
    _arr.push( i + ";" + arr[index] + ";" + arr[index + 1] + ";" + arr[index + 2] + "<br />\n");
    index = index + 3;
}
_arr = _arr.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
var file = new Blob([_arr], {
    "type": "text/plain"
});

// ... code to write it back in txt file
 }
```

Thanks a lot @ all for your Help

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at what you've got: you have a text block, with numbers separated by spaces.  That's something we can work with.

The .split(" ") function will separate the numbers and put them in an array; you could do a 
     getNP01TableData.split(" ") and your result will be:

```
["  ", "134.45  ", "987.46  ", "-89.10", "
    ", "224.67  ", "127.26  ", "-19.12
    ", "764.32  ", "187.96  ", "-78.25" ]
```

And that definitely looks like something you can work with.  Throw that bad boy into a loop:

```
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length/3; i++) {
    text = text + i;
    for (j = 0; j<3; j++) {
       text=text+";"+arr[3*i + j]
    }
    text = text+"</br";
}
```

That might need a little fiddling, but you get the idea.  Also, the .trim() function is useful for removing unwanted whitespace.

Comment: hm.. something will not work. i've tryed to put it in like that
`function LineWriteToNp01() { 

 var getNP01TableData = $('#null_tabelle_dues1_text').text().split(" ");

 var text = [getNP01TableData];
 for (var i = 0; i<arr.length/3; i++) {
  text = text + i;
  for (j = 0; j<3; j++) {
     text=text+";"+arr[3*i + j]
  }
  text = text+"</br>";
 }
  alert (text);
  }`
whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var text = "134.45   987.46   -89.10 224.67   127.26   -19.12 764.32   187.96   -78.25";

var arr = $.map(text.split(" "), function (value, index) {
    return value === "" ? null : [value]
});

var _arr = [];
_arr.push("1;" + arr.slice(0, 3).join(",").replace(/,/g, ";") + "<br />");
_arr.push("2;" + arr.slice(3, 6).join(",").replace(/,/g, ";") + "<br />");
_arr.push("3;" + arr.slice(6, 9).join(",").replace(/,/g, ";") + "<br />");    
_arr = _arr.toString().replace(/,/g, "");

var file = new Blob([_arr], {
    "type": "text/plain"
});

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.result);
});
reader.readAsText(file);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/YpBxA/

Comment: this is really good, but the nummbers are coming sometimes wit 100 lines, not only 3. should be more dynamic.
but thanks for the idea :)

Comment: now i have the Idea. Thank you for your Help. see in my answer below the working result.